# Reprojection of Landsat 8 using the existing shapefile in ArcGis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.0, vector, proj

I have downloaded a landsat8 and when I overlay it with a shapefile of the location where I want to extract by mask , the combination of landsat 8 and the shapefile are not matching. The shapefile is outside of the landsat image. I reprojected the landsat8 using the same projection system but the problem is still there.

Is there another way I can fix that problem?

Comment: How did you reproject the Landsat 8 image? The Project Raster tool is the only way. Please edit your question with the original extents and coordinate reference systems (CRS) of the image and the shapefile.

Comment: 1. Data Type: Shapefile Feature Class 
Projected Coordinate System: WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_36S
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting: 500000.00000000
False_Northing: 10000000.00000000
Central_Meridian: 33.00000000
Scale_Factor: 0.99960000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.00000000
Linear Unit:  Meter
Datum:  D_WGS_1984
2. And this "WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_36S" for landsat8 but the two images are not matching and i used the project raster in projecting the landsat

Comment: Hi, thank you but please edit the question with this information. Comments are sometimes deleted and the information lost. We also need the extents of the datasets. By looking at the extents, you can see if they make sense against the CRS and sometimes what the CRS should be--one of the CRS is probably incorrect.